# Preferences in SQL-Developer for only one Column?

Tags: sql, oracle, preferences

Let's say you have 3 'DATE_COLUMNS' in a TABLE.

Is it then possible to set a preference per COLUMN.

I'd like only 2 of the 3 columns to have the Date_Format: `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS`

The other 1 should have the Date Format: `DD-MM-YYYY`

Now if I'm setting the preferences via Tools >> Preferences >> Database >> NLS it sets the preferences for the whole Database, so for every Column in there...

Comment: Dates are stored using an internal format.  The date format comes into play when you convert it into a string for output purposes.

Comment: @ogieogilthorpe: Do you use sqlplus ? Look for `format` in sqlplus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible, as a column of type `DATE` stores a Date/Time, which is *not a string*. The column stores no information about what format is preferred or intended for its conversion.

The value is converted to a string at the client depending on the NLS settings; you can override this at query time using the `to_char(datecol,'format')` function.

The ability to override the NLS settings for individual columns might be an interesting feature to request for SQL Developer.